# Infinite List of type variables - Type Inference

Tags: haskell, type-inference

Given an type involving type variables, is there a way to defined an infinite list of type variables in which no type variable are ever repeated?

Let me provide more context with my question. I'm working on a type inference of my own in Haskell. My data type looks like this:

```
data Ty = TyUnit
        | TyVar String
        | TyBool
        | TyInt
        | TyBoolList
        | TyIntList
        | Arrow Ty Ty
```

I gave the definition of the type above. I believe that the function is supposed to generate an infinite list of variable names. I'm just confused on how to proceed and the actual implementation of the question.

Comment: Do you mean a list of Ty objects such that all possible combinations are used and no repeat?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is something you'd ever need when building a type inferencer, besides a potentially non-terminating brute-force approach. As I understand it, you usually want something like `freshTyVars = map (TyVar . ("_fresh_"++) . show) [0..]`, or actually `type FreshVars = [String]` and plugging these into `TyVar`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
allTys 0 = TyUnit : TyVar "?" : TyBool : TyInt : TyBoolList :  TyIntList : []
allTys n = [0..n-1] >>= (\i -> liftM2 Arrow (allTys i) (allTys (n-1-i))) 

allTypes = [0..] >>= allTys
```

`allTys n` constructs a type tree of height n. Here height of `Arrow x y` is height of x + height of y + 1 and height of everything else is 0. The construction is very basic. I'm not sure if it can be done faster. Ask in the comments, if it needs more explaining.

Also, in case that is needed, this is how to get all strings of an alphabet (say `['a'..'z']`) .

```
strings alphabet = (:) [] $ liftM2 (flip (:)) (strings alphabet) alphabet
```

The idea that a long string is a `somechar:shortstring`. Note that the empty string is included.

Comment: -1: The question asks for an infinite list of type variables, so this is not a solution.

Comment: @cebewee, do you think he wanted a list of TyVar only? I wrote my answer based on "FreshTyVars is supposed to generate an infinite list of non-repeating types, meaning it could be infinite cases of nested Arrow statements".

Comment: Juodele: The question starts with: "Given an type FreshVars = [Ty], is there a way to defined an infinite list of type variables in which no type variable are ever repeated". But you are correct, later he talks about general types. I'd un-(-1) (although I guess this is not what he wants), but my vote is locked now.

Comment: @juodele i was thinking more about what the question is asking and I believe that the question asks to generate an infinite list of variable names, which are all unique

Comment: @NuNu, it's your question, why would you have to think about what it is asking? So you just want an infinite list of strings? What do types have to do with that?

Comment: @juodele types are important because I'm working on a type inference in Haskell

Comment: @NuNu, okay. Is my edit satisfactory? Of course, you'd do `map TyVar $ strings ['a'..'z']` to use it. Do you get how it works?